# Cannot add any UIView to my main UIViewController, after dismissing another UIViewController

Tags: swift, uiview, addsubview, dismiss, presentviewcontroller

I have a main ViewController that eventually creates and presents a new ViewController, which is used to gather some user data. When the data is picked, I dismiss the second ViewController and use the completion field of the func "dismissViewControllerAnimated" to call a method from a delegate that lets me hand in the data to the first and main ViewController (it is important to say that this method, actually sends an instance of a class with the data, created and initialized just before calling "dismissViewControllerAnimated").

At the first and main ViewController, I have defined the delegate method to do the following:

· print the data fields of the received instance, to make sure I have my data on the ViewController I want.

· Call a method from the received instance's class, that creates and initializes a UIlabel with the data just printed in the previos step (this label is stored into one of this ViewController properties).

· self.view.addSubview(/* property of UILabel type, now filled with my own UILabel */)

Everything compiles and goes perfect till the addSubview part... I also print the property once is filled, to make sure it receives the correct data, and it does. But no UILabel appears on my first ViewController View. Also, I have made many tests through other methods, and after dismissing the second ViewController, no UIView of any kind is successfully displayed on the screen.

I have also tried to use self.view.reloadInputView() after addSubview, but although it compiles, it has no effect.

Could anyone offer me a clue or something that helps me know how are UIViews displayed after dismissing another ViewController? My code is written in swift.

Comment: Curiously, I have just discovered something that works, at least in a provisional way. It is as follows:                                                                               "UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.self.presentViewController(self, animated: true, completion: nil)" Does anyone knows what does this sentence mean? And also... since it is my first post in this forum and I am not used to its protocol, should I rewrite this as a separate answer to my post?